# Javascript array of objects sort by property isn't working

Tags: javascript

I have an array of person objects, each with a name and a score property. I want to sort the array by the person object's score property and then display the array.

I have a function to display the rankings and I've added the sort code to the top of that function, but it is not sorting the array and no errors are being thrown. Any ideas what's wrong?

The javascript code:

```
var rankings = [];

/* Player object constructor */

function Player(pname, score) { 
        this.pname = pname;
        this.score = score;
    }

/* function to add new players removed for clarity, it works */


/* sort and display the player objects by score */

function displayRankings () {

        rankings.sort( function(a, b) {
            return a[1] - b[1];
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < rankings.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var node = document.createTextNode(rankings[i].pname + ", " + rankings[i].score);
            li.appendChild(node);

            var element = document.getElementById("rankings");
            element.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should provide minimal data to your `rankings`, otherwise we can't determine whether it's a data problem. (I guess your sort function is simply wrong, try `a.score - b.score` instead)

Comment: Not sure what data to provide, as there really isn't much more than the html and the function code to add players to the array. Changing to a.score - b.score did the trick. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `rankings` is an array of `Person` objects, then you need to be accessing the `score` property, not `[1]`.

```
rankings.sort( function(a, b) {
    return a.score - b.score;
});
```